Iteration and stop condition on server side in Google Earth Engine
To iterate a process that updates image collection (i.e., take image collection, do multiple process that can't be achieved with map alone, and returns updated image collection once a condition is met), client side functions such as for and while are not valid options, and iterate is probably among the best options! I would like to clarify the best practice to apply such iteration with a stop condition!
With reference to the helpful answers of similar questions here and here, I used .iterate() on a sequential list of a user-specified max number of iteration, and evaluated the condition using ee.Algorithms.If on previous (return previous for true, and updated for false). Here is the link for the full toy code with manual validation. Relevant code block is also repeated below
There are two major issues that concerns me in such implementation:

Although this function returns the Image collection at which the condition is met, I assume it's unnecessarily continue the computation till the max number of iterations is reached rather than stopping when the condition is met. Is there a way to stop when condition is met?
ee.Algorithms.If is not recommended for branching logic. Is this the case here? and if so, what could be an alternative?

The user-specified max number of iteration allows me to calibrate the number of iteration manually by evaluating the condition outside of the iteration for each given number, but I imagine that is also far a way from a best practice
// A function to iterate (Toy): A function to update image collection: take a collection, call user specified functions and return an updated image collection
var UpdateCollection = function (Index, Collection) {
  Collection = ee.ImageCollection(Collection);
  var output_f1 = func1(Collection); // user specified function
  var image = output_f1.first().select("SR_B1").divide(4).abs(); // do things with user specified function
  var UpdatedCollection = Collection.map(function (img) {
    // do things to update Collection
    return img
      .divide(10)
      .subtract(10)
      .subtract(image)
      .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());
  });

  var condition = Calc_condition(UpdatedCollection); //user specified function to calculate condition
  condition = ee.Number(condition);
  Index = ee.Number(Index).add(1); //add 1 to obtain consistent  index of number of iteration
  UpdatedCollection = UpdatedCollection.set({
    IterationNumber: ee.Number(Index),
    condition: ee.Number(condition),
  });

  // evaluate condition based on previous: if conditon met return previous one, if not return updated
  var Collcondition = Calc_condition(Collection);
  UpdatedCollection = ee.Algorithms.If(
    Collcondition.lt(0),
    Collection,
    UpdatedCollection,
  );
  UpdatedCollection = ee.ImageCollection(UpdatedCollection);

  return UpdatedCollection;
};

// get the initial Coll to start iteration
var StartColl = UpdateCollection(-1, Coll); // -1 is to obtain consistent index of number of iteration

// Iterate
var max_N_of_Iteration = 6; // Max Number of iteration after the first one
var listOfIteration = ee.List.sequence(0, max_N_of_Iteration - 1, 1); // Convergence happened at the 3rd iteration
var Finalresult = ee.ImageCollection(
  listOfIteration.iterate(UpdateCollection, StartColl),
);

// Show the result and check the condition to decide the number of iteration: Stop when the reduction result is less than 0
var condition = ee.Number(Finalresult.get("condition"));
var evaluateCondition = ee.Algorithms.If(
  condition.lt(0),
  "Condition is met:",
  "Condition is not met,results are invalid: try higher number of iterations!",
);
print(
  evaluateCondition,
  condition,
  "number of iteration:",
  Finalresult.get("IterationNumber"),
);
Map.addLayer(Finalresult, null, "Final result");

print(Finalresult, "Final result");

